# Go listen on port which is already in use not returning error

Tags: go

I already have a webserver which is listening on port 80 (written in node.js). When I run another webserver that also listens on port 80 (written in Go), the Go webserver doesn't raise an error.

How can this occur.

My OS is windows and go version go1.2.2.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the actual question is.

Comment: I mean if a program want listen on port which have been used,it should return error or thow exception,but golang program do not.

Comment: Once again, that's not a question.

Comment: It happens when your golang listens to both IPv6 and v4 addresses. Whereas the other app is IPv4 only.

Comment: How I make it listen only on Ipv4 address

Comment: But it's backwards to only support IPv4

Comment: @Simeon I'd be interested in knowing how to make it fail if it can't get the port on both IPv6 and IPv4.

Comment: Some things related to dual stack [Golang net.Listen binds to port that's already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071020/golang-net-listen-binds-to-port-thats-already-in-use)

Comment: Instead of `http.ListenAndServe(port, ...)` use `l, err := net.Listen("tcp4", port)` then `http.Serve(l, ...)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this happen at work. The golang server will be listening to the IPv6 port 80 while the other application is only listening to IPv4.

For me the golang app was running first. And it stop listening to v4 and then resumed once the other app was closed.

[edit later]
To demostrate this, I just ran the WinSock bind/listen C++ code found on this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739168(v=vs.85).aspx) page with the port changed to 80, then I used this Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("c:\\temp")))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil))
}
```

This setup worked because the C++ was listening to `127.0.0.1` and the Go on `0.0.0.0` Changing the go code to `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:80", nil))` caused the error message nemo suggested.

I then started my main production code, which has a Mongoose HTTP instance, and it's listening on `0.0.0.0:80`, and then ran the above Go code (removing 127.0.0.1) and both are listening to `0.0.0.0:80`, this can be seen via Process Explorer.

[image: both apps listening to 0.0.0.0:80]

Comment: Did you try to make them exclusive on port 80 (as per OP)? Do you find a solution?

Comment: @rick-777 the other server was the old server I was developing a replacement for. So I just had to remove the calls that started it. So it was a too much running in dec box issue not production problem.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I changed net.Listen("tcp", addr) to net.Listen("tcp4", addr) and now I get an error if the port is in use.

Answer (score 0):

Go reports errors just fine. You're probably missing to check the returned error value.

#### test.go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

#### testing

```
$ nc -l 8080
$ go run test.go
2014/06/30 08:40:49 listen tcp :8080: bind: address already in use
exit status 1
```

Comment: `err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil);`
when I run on windows,the `err` is `nil`

Comment: Your forgetting ipv6 and ipv4 both have a port 80

Answer (score -2):

You can't run two applications on the same port, also you need to check for errors returned when calling functions :

```
if err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Your forgetting ipv6 and ipv4 both have a port 80