# Golang net.Listen binds to port that's already in use

Tags: python, macos, sockets, go, networking

Port 8888 is already bound on my (OS X 10.13.5) system, by a process running inside a docker container:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 8888
tcp6       0      0  ::1.8888               *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.8888                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

A python program which tries to bind to that port (using as close to the socket options of golang as I can manage), fails in the way I expect:

```python
import socket
import fcntl
import os


def main():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    flag = fcntl.fcntl(sock.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(sock.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, flag | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 8888))
    sock.listen(5)


main()
```

fails with:

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 11, in main
    sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 8888))
OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

But a go program creating a connection via `net.Listen` does not fail, as I expect it to:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    _, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:8888")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Connection error: %s\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Listening")
    }
}
```

Succeeds with:

```
$ go run test.go
Listening
```

A coworker reports that with the same setup, his Ubuntu system correctly fails the go program.

Why does this succeed on a Mac, and how can I get the net.Listen to show an error in binding to port 8888?

edit: If I occupy port 8888 with a simple go program like:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:8888", nil))
}
```

Then `test.go` correctly fails to bind to the port. However the docker process (which is running basically that ^^^) does not cause it to fail.

edit 2: If I specify "tcp4", then the program does indeed fail as I expect. If I specify "tcp6", it succeeds but netstat says it binds to `*` instead of `::1`:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 8888
tcp6       0      0  *.8888                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  ::1.8888               *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.8888                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

So, specifying "tcp4" will solve my actual problem, but I really want to understand what the heck is going on with the "tcp46" connection type, and I can't find any documentation. Help!

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're not running an old build with a different port or something..? `http.ListenAndServe` also calls `net.Listen("tcp", addr)` internally: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/server.go#L2728

Comment: yup, 100% certain

Comment: It might be useful to add a `time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)` call to the end of your Go program and get `netstat` output while it's running.

Comment: Excellent idea: https://gist.github.com/llimllib/9f86f61a9436e9f59edf39d97c9b8dca . It binds to `tcp46` instead of `tcp4` or `tcp6`, but I don't know what that really means?

Comment: Can you provide the output to `lsof -i -T f | grep 8888` while the Go program is running?

Comment: @chuckx `lsof -i -T f | grep 8888` is empty both before the program runs and while it runs, are you sure those are correct Mac lsof options?

Comment: @chuckx ok, I think I found the relevant results in the output, they don't list the port number but here they are: https://gist.github.com/llimllib/854d8b737ad2405479b64eb5f70ce0fa

Comment: @chuckx thank you for the idea! Here is a _much_ faster lsof invocation to study the problem: `lsof -i :8888 -T f` (which outputs the same as before)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I think I have a story to tell about why this happens:

1. Docker on mac, when mapping a port, binds to IPv4 `0.0.0.0:<port>` and IPv6 `[::1]:<port>`. Note that on IPv6 it maps to the equivalent of `localhost` rather than `0.0.0.0`, which would be `[::]`!
2. Golang, when opening a socket to listen on, by default opens an IPv6 socket that is mapped in some way to also listen to IPv4. (I still don't completely understand this `tcp46` type, so if you have good docs *please* point me to them!).
3. So my golang program was opening an IPv6 socket on `[::]:8888`, the equivalent of `0.0.0.0:8888` in IPv6. This succeeded because docker was listening on `[::1]` (the equivalent of 127.0.0.1), *not* `[::]`
4. That's it! So the golang program succeeded even though it will only get connected to by a client connecting on IPv6 from a non-loopback address (I think, I got too tired to test this, give me a break)

My coworker reports that on Ubuntu, docker listens on `[::]`, which is why he was unable to reproduce the problem I was seeing. This seems like the sensible behavior! And I have no idea why it doesn't do so on mac.

I also think it's surprising and possibly a bit wrong that Go happily succeeds in this instance, even though it's creating a socket that's very difficult to actually access? But I can't say that it's definitely a bug, and I *definitely* don't feel like trying to report it as such to the go project.

Comment: I ran into this as well, thanks for the explanation. This is very unintuitive behavior, and it's not mentioned in the docs at all. I guess if you want to force an error, you have to manually listen on `tcp4` rather than using `listenAndServe` wrapper? Like https://github.com/shazow/ssh-chat/issues/139

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the `tcp46` output from `netstat`, I can't find any documentation but I did find the relevant source.

From [network_cmds-543/netstat.proj/inet.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-543/netstat.tproj/inet.c.auto.html):

```
void
protopr(uint32_t proto,     /* for sysctl version we pass proto # */
        char *name, int af)
{

...

    struct xinpcb_n *inp = NULL;

...

            const char *vchar;

#ifdef INET6
            if ((inp->inp_vflag & INP_IPV6) != 0)
                vchar = ((inp->inp_vflag & INP_IPV4) != 0)
                ? "46" : "6 ";
            else
#endif
                vchar = ((inp->inp_vflag & INP_IPV4) != 0)
                ? "4 " : "  ";
```

`xinpcb_n` is defined in [bsd/netinet/in_pcb.h](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/0a798f6738bc1db01281fc08ae024145e84df927/bsd/netinet/in_pcb.h#L425).

```
 * struct inpcb captures the network layer state for TCP, UDP and raw IPv6
 * and IPv6 sockets.
```

Elsewhere in that file, the `inp_vflag` is documented as `/* INP_IPV4 or INP_IPV6 */`. Those are in turn defined as:

```
#define INP_IPV4    0x1
#define INP_IPV6    0x2
```

So basically, when a socket has both v4 and v6 bits set, it will display `46` in the protocol column.

---

Regarding Go, there's [this `socket()` function in the net package](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/ef9217e7bd9c854e4f8d2d79ff8aec550130cbc4/src/net/sock_posix.go#L18):

```
func socket(ctx context.Context, net string, family, sotype, proto int, ipv6only bool, laddr, raddr sockaddr, ctrlFn func(string, string, syscall.RawConn) error) (fd *netFD, err error) {

...

if err = setDefaultSockopts(s, family, sotype, ipv6only); err != nil {
```

`setDefaultSockopts()` has per platform definitions, here's an excerpt from [the BSD variant](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/257d6c48e0abde069e5acc67f719a129d0017186/src/net/sockopt_bsd.go#L15):

```
func setDefaultSockopts(s, family, sotype int, ipv6only bool) error {

...

    if supportsIPv4map() && family == syscall.AF_INET6 && sotype != syscall.SOCK_RAW {
        // Allow both IP versions even if the OS default
        // is otherwise. Note that some operating systems
        // never admit this option.
        syscall.SetsockoptInt(s, syscall.IPPROTO_IPV6, syscall.IPV6_V6ONLY, boolint(ipv6only))
```

So, allowing of both IP versions on a socket is driven by the `ipv6Only` boolean. After a little more digging, I found [where this is decided](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/ef9217e7bd9c854e4f8d2d79ff8aec550130cbc4/src/net/ipsock_posix.go#L72) and includes a detailed explanation of the logic:

```
// favoriteAddrFamily returns the appropriate address family for the
// given network, laddr, raddr and mode.
//
// If mode indicates "listen" and laddr is a wildcard, we assume that
// the user wants to make a passive-open connection with a wildcard
// address family, both AF_INET and AF_INET6, and a wildcard address
// like the following:
//
//  - A listen for a wildcard communication domain, "tcp" or
//    "udp", with a wildcard address: If the platform supports
//    both IPv6 and IPv4-mapped IPv6 communication capabilities,
//    or does not support IPv4, we use a dual stack, AF_INET6 and
//    IPV6_V6ONLY=0, wildcard address listen. The dual stack
//    wildcard address listen may fall back to an IPv6-only,
//    AF_INET6 and IPV6_V6ONLY=1, wildcard address listen.
//    Otherwise we prefer an IPv4-only, AF_INET, wildcard address
//    listen.
//
//  - A listen for a wildcard communication domain, "tcp" or
//    "udp", with an IPv4 wildcard address: same as above.
//
//  - A listen for a wildcard communication domain, "tcp" or
//    "udp", with an IPv6 wildcard address: same as above.
//
//  - A listen for an IPv4 communication domain, "tcp4" or "udp4",
//    with an IPv4 wildcard address: We use an IPv4-only, AF_INET,
//    wildcard address listen.
//
//  - A listen for an IPv6 communication domain, "tcp6" or "udp6",
//    with an IPv6 wildcard address: We use an IPv6-only, AF_INET6
//    and IPV6_V6ONLY=1, wildcard address listen.
//
// Otherwise guess: If the addresses are IPv4 then returns AF_INET,
// or else returns AF_INET6. It also returns a boolean value what
// designates IPV6_V6ONLY option.
//
// Note that the latest DragonFly BSD and OpenBSD kernels allow
// neither "net.inet6.ip6.v6only=1" change nor IPPROTO_IPV6 level
// IPV6_V6ONLY socket option setting.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I don't think we would have cracked it without that lsof, and this is valuable information on this strange corner of unix networking :)